# Checking PUT request from server for extra fields as JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to send PUT request and I want to check if there're some extra fields. Is there any chance to check these extra fields, so I can throw an exception?
For example, I've got this JSON file and this one is okay to add

```
    "id": 9999,
    "name": "Film Updated",
    "description": "New film update decription",
    "releaseDate": "1989-04-17",
    "duration": 190
```

As you can see, in the following file, there's an extra field `rate`

```
  "id": 9999,
  "name": "Film Updated",
  "releaseDate": "1989-04-17",
  "description": "New film update decription",
  "duration": 190,
  "rate": 4
```

So I want to check if PUT request contains any extra fields to prevent from putting this information into HashMap. The following method is putting information into HashMap

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/films")
    public Film create(@Valid @RequestBody Film film) {
        if (film.getDuration() <= 0
                || film.getReleaseDate().isBefore(FILM_DATE)
                || film.getDescription().length() > 200 || film.getName().isEmpty()) {
            throw new ValidationException("Incorrect data");
        } else {
            if (film.getId() == 0) {
                film.setId(1);
            }
            log.info("'{}' movie was added to a library, the identifier is '{}'", film.getName(), film.getId());
            films.put(film.getId(), film);
        }
        return film;
    }
```

But I have no idea how to check extra fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use extra properties from JSON. The best option for that is to create DTO object only with properties that you want to use called for example `FilmDTO` with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` class annotation.

I would also recommend not to put all the logic inside of Controller Class, try to create for example `FilmService` which will encapsulate whole business logic inside:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class FilmController {

    private final FilmService filmService;

    public FilmController(FilmService filmService) {
        this.filmService = filmService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/films")
    public Film create(@RequestBody @Validated FilmDTO filmDTO ){
        return filmService.addFilm(filmDTO);
    }
}
```

Film

```
public class Film {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final LocalDate releaseDate;
    private final int duration;

    public Film(Integer id, String name, String description, LocalDate releaseDate, int duration) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public static Film fromDto(FilmDTO filmDto) {
        return new Film(filmDto.getId(), filmDto.getName(), filmDto.getDescription(), filmDto.getReleaseDate(), filmDto.getDuration());
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public LocalDate getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Film film = (Film) o;
        return duration == film.duration && Objects.equals(id, film.id) && Objects.equals(name, film.name) && Objects.equals(description, film.description) && Objects.equals(releaseDate, film.releaseDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, description, releaseDate, duration);
    }
}
```

FilmDto

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FilmDTO {
    private final Integer id;
    @NotEmpty
    private final String name;
    @Size(max = 200)
    private final String description;
    private final LocalDate releaseDate;
    @Min(value = 1)
    private final int duration;

    public FilmDTO(Integer id, String name, String description, LocalDate releaseDate, int duration) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public LocalDate getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        FilmDTO filmDTO = (FilmDTO) o;
        return duration == filmDTO.duration && Objects.equals(id, filmDTO.id) && Objects.equals(name, filmDTO.name) && Objects.equals(description, filmDTO.description) && Objects.equals(releaseDate, filmDTO.releaseDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, description, releaseDate, duration);
    }
}
```

FilmService

```
@Service
public class FilmService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FilmService.class);
    // Change that hashmap with some sort of repository.
    private final Map<Integer, Film> films = new HashMap<>();

    public Film addFilm(FilmDTO filmDTO) {
        if (filmDTO.getReleaseDate().isBefore(FILM_DATE)) {
            logger.error("Validation exception");
            throw new ValidationException("Incorrect data");
        }
        Film addedFilm = Film.fromDto(filmDTO);
        logger.info("'{}' movie was added to a library, the identifier is '{}'", addedFilm.getName(), addedFilm.getId());
        films.put(addedFilm.getId(), addedFilm);
        return addedFilm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will throw an exception that you can gracefully handle. However, you might want to move the processFilm method to a service class.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping()
public class EmployeeController {
    private static final LocalDate FILM_DATE = LocalDate.now();

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @PostMapping(value = "/films")
    public Film create(@RequestBody String requestBody) {
        Map<Integer, Film> films = new HashMap<>();

        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        Film film;
        try {
           film = objectMapper.readValue(requestBody, Film.class);
            processFilm(films, film);
            return film;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Invalid request body", e);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Unable to convert request body", e);
        }
    }

    private static void processFilm(Map<Integer, Film> films, Film film) {
        if (film.getDuration() <= 0
                || film.getReleaseDate().isAfter(FILM_DATE)
                || film.getDescription().length() > 200 || film.getName().isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect data");
        } else {
            if (film.getId() == 0) {
                film.setId(1);
            }
            log.info("'{}' movie was added to a library, the identifier is '{}'", film.getName(), film.getId());
            films.put(film.getId(), film);
        }
    }


}
```